# Does original database change in knime

Tags: database, knime

When using the database manipulation nodes, does the original database data would change or remain the same?
Can anyone answer please?

Answer (score 1):

If you write to or update the database, the original database will be updated. Read or query operations such as row / column filtering, row sampling, groupby and joiner do not change the underlying database

Comment: thanks for info! But, my doubt was the nodes like database row filter, database sampling etc.., the manipulating nodes in knime node repository would change actual database data?